# one address multiple inputs one signature scheme

Tags: scalability, cross-input-signature-aggregation

I have an idea and would like to know if current or future technology can allow it :

Assume 100 people with index i
each people has secret Ri
Secrets Ri are combined via an abstract mechanism to produce a public root address P0
everybody from Root address P0 and index i can compute address Pi
Only the ith people can spend from Pi via his secret Ri
assume a mechanism to aggregate signatures Si

So that a 100 people spend to a business investment address for example could use only 1 input address and 1 signature saving 99 signatures and 99 input addresses.

Is it feasible ? How hard would it be to implement on bitcoin ? Can we do that with Schnorr Signatures ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, BLS signatures could do indexed key aggregation with m-n signatures

Comment: BLS signatures would need to be activated on Bitcoin mainnet (or a sidechain), they currently aren't available on mainnet. MuSig2 uses Schnorr and so is available on Bitcoin mainnet today.